# Trouble Linking libsndfile in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: dll, linker, visual-studio-express, libsndfile

I've been attempting to use libsndfile (it is the windows 64 bit version) for the first time, and have encountered a problem while trying to link it. Whenever I try to compile the program, I get this error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sf_close referenced in function _main

This is the process I've done so far to attempt to link it to the program.

In project properties I have gone to Config. Prop.-> VC++ Directories, and added the path to the header files to the include directories tab, and the path to the .lib files to library directories tab.

In C/C++-> General-> Additional Include Directories, I have added the path to the header files.

In Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies I have added the path to the .lib file, which for me is C:\Program Files\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\lib\libsndfile-1.lib

I've added #include  "sndfile.h" to the .cpp file but for some reason it doesn't seem to have access to the functions in the dll. I don't really know a lot about linking, and what I've done is just what I've been able to piece together from scouring the internet, so I'm not really sure on what I'm doing wrong or right. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably compiling a 32 bit project in Visual Studio, and trying to link it with a 64 bit library. It won't work... download the 32 bit version of the windows binary of libsndfile and use it to link to your executable. Another option is to create a 64 bit project, but I think the first option is (slightly) easier.